# JavaFX - setOnAction not applicable

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to learn JavaFX, and I've written the code shown down below, however I seem to be having trouble with this line of code:

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
```

where it underlines setOnAction, and prints this Error:

```
 The method setOnAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent>) in the type ButtonBase is not applicable for the arguments (new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){})
```

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World' ");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
             @Override
             public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                 System.out.println("Button clicked");
             }
         });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You imported `java.awt.event.ActionEvent` you need to change this to `javafx.event.ActionEvent`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have imported awt event listener just change this line of code

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
```

with this

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
```

and you can also use lambda expression like this

```
btn.setOnAction((event) -> {
  System.out.println("Button clicked");
});
```

Comment: upvote and accept the answer if you found it helpful

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up Javafx with Swing. Replace

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
```

with

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
```